# FWTools ogr2ogr command does not seem to recognise dim parameter

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, fwtools

I am trying to convert a 3D shapefile to 2D via FWTools shell.

This is the command I am trying

```
ogr2ogr REGC2013_GV_Clipped_lonlat_2d.shp REGC2013_GV_Clipped_lonlat.shp -dim 2
```

Which returns the Usage - there is no mention of the dim parameter in the usage. It does not output a new shapefile. I have managed to convert a shapefile from map projection to lonlat coordinates using this

```
ogr2ogr REGC2013_GV_Clipped_lonlat.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326 REGC2013_GV_Clipped.shp
```

but if I add the -dim 2 it does not work and I get the usage returned.

I am using Windows 7 and this is the version info

```
C:Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Plotting>gdalinfo --version
GDAL 1.7.0b2, FWTools 2.4.7, released 2010/01/19
```

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from the [ogr2ogr help page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html):

> **-dim val**
>
> (starting with GDAL 1.10) Force the coordinate dimension to val (valid
>   values are 2 or 3). This affects both the layer geometry type, and
>   feature geometries. Starting with GDAL 2.0, the value can be set to
>   "layer_dim" to instruct feature geometries to be promoted to the
>   coordinate dimension declared by the layer.

Comment: OK I need a later version 1.7 must not be recent enough.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded OSGeo4W http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
and installed the GDal packages, the current GDal version installed is 1.10 and then this command worked fine:

```
ogr2ogr REGC2013_GV_Clipped_lonlat_2d.shp REGC2013_GV_Clipped_lonlat.shp -dim 2
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also install the GDAL package by http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/